# Laravel Office365 Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""

Tags: laravel, smtp, office365, swiftmailer

Need help setting up Mail on my Laravel application.

My .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*****@*****.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

This returns the following error :

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""
```

Comment: jeeees...I am facing this exact same issue right now!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turns out Office 365 doesn't let you use a different `from` setting in your mail sending function than the one you use in your `.env` file.

I wanted to set the `from` name and email address according to whatever data was coming in via the request of a form submission as to capture them in the CRM system and it threw that same exception. Not sure if this helps you, but this was how I solved my problem.

Here's my code in the controller as an example:

```
$data = [
   'name' => $request->get('name'),
   'surname' => $request->get('surname'),
   'email' => $request->get('email'),
   'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
    'subject' => $request->get('message-subject')
];

$from = $data['name'] . ' ' . $data['surname'];
            Mail::send('mail.mymail', compact('data'), function($message) use ($request, $data, $from) {
                                $message->to('example@companyiworkfor.com', 'Some Company I Work For')->subject('Website Contact Form');
                                $message->from($data['email'], $from);
// Office 365 won't let you use a different from address here,so use same email as per your .env
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

We were getting the same error message in one of our customer's internal tool, which runs on Symfony 3 and Swiftmailer v5.4.4.

After some debugging, I found out that there was a previous exception thrown by Swiftmailer. The reason was the response from smtp.office365.com:

> 421 4.7.66 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_tls. [AM6PR02CA0020.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com]

Microsoft dropped support for TLS 1.0 und 1.1. After some research I found [this](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/1099#issuecomment-408357884) github issue:

> This commit ([4c4b333](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/commit/4c4b333c9164b74aaceb7ff9bef2d55f7a5514b8)) introduced TLS 1.1 / 1.2 support, but didn't make it to any release yet. Unfortunately all Swiftmailer users (besides the ones using recent dev-master) are tied to TLS 1.0, which starts to give issues

In one of the comments @fabpot replied that they've backported the bugfix to Swiftmailer 5. It landed in release `5.4.10`.

After upgrading Swiftmailer, the mailing worked again.